# When exploring data, box plots won't share pages with other diagrams in Rattle

Tags: r, rattle

I am currently working through Data Mining with Rattle and R by Williams. I am on page 32 of his book and on the following tab in Rattle:

Explore > Distributions

Reiterating the title, when exploring the data, box plots won't share pages with other diagrams.

For example, when I do box plots and histograms for `MinTemp` and `Sunshine` I get a page with the histogram diagrams on it and a separate page for each of the box plot diagrams.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when I stumbled over your post. What solved the issue for me, after trying to install various recommended packages, was just to disable in the Rattle settings "Advanced Graphics". After that, the boxplot worked as described in the tutorials.

Hope that helps you